# Show that any element of $A$ has a unique representation in the form $a+f(x)x+g(y)y, \ a\in k, f\in k[x], g \in k[y].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$. Show that any element of $A$ has a unique representation in the form $$a+f(x)x+g(y)y, \ a\in k, f\in k[x], g \in k[y].$$

By definition any $u \in A$ is of the form $u=f(x,y)+(xy) = \{f(x,y) + h(x,y)x+g(x,y)y \mid f,h,g \in k[x,y]\}.$

I think that $u$ can be thought of $f(x,y) + $ a remainder of polynomial $p(x,y)$ upon division with $xy$?

The problem seems to make $f(x,y)$ a constant term somehow which I don't understand here. If I divide any polynmial in $A$ with $xy$, then the degree of the remainder should be $0$ always?

Does the geometric picture of $k[x,y]/(xy)$ help here? It's supposedly the disjoint union of $x$ and $y$-axes in $k^2$?

The problem is from Reid's undergraduate commutative algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $f \in k[x,y]$ can be written :
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}x^ny^m$$
where $(a_{n,m})$ is a family of elements of $k$, almost all of whom are zero.

Then, since $x^ny^m \equiv 0 \mod (xy)$ if $n\geq 1$ and $m\geq 1$, we have :
\begin{align}
f(x) &\equiv a_{0,0} + \sum_{n\geq 1} a_{n,0}x^n + \sum_{m\geq 1} a_{0,m}y^m &\mod (xy) \\
&\equiv a + x g(x) + yh(y) &\mod (xy)
\end{align}

where $a= a_{0,0}$, $g(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_{n+1,0}x^n$ and $h(y)=\sum_{m\geq 0} a_{0,m+1}y^m$.